# Cnn keras model what no of trained parameter represents and improve the model

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am looking for some useful suggestions for keras cnn model.
i have a very small dataset(144 images) which i am training through `keras cnn` i tried to add many `layers` and `num_of_filters` but the accuracy is not increasing even number of `trained parameter` was 111,453,342. Does large number of parameters represents more chance to get good accuracy? And below is my existing model it gives `val_acc=0.56`. How i can improve my model.

```
inputs=Input(shape=(100,100,1))
x=Conv2D(28, (5, 5), padding='same')(inputs)
x=SReLU()(x)
x=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(1, 1))(x)
x=Conv2D(14, (4, 4), padding='same')(x)
x=SReLU()(x)
x=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(1, 1))(x)
x=Conv2D(7, (3, 3), padding='same')(x)
x=SReLU()(x)
x=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x=Flatten()(x)
x=Dropout(0.2)(x)
x=Dense(512)(x)
x=SReLU()(x)
#x=keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
x=Dropout(0.2)(x)
x=Dense(num_classes)(x)

output=Activation('softmax')(x)
model=Model([inputs], output)
```

Comment: This is not suited for stackoverflow. Also the number of parameters is a difficult quantity. It somewhat tells you about the complexity of your model. Without good regularization you're more likely to overfit if you have many parameters. Also it can make training in general very difficult. Best approach is to start simple/shallow and then add complexity to your model.

Comment: Try get more data for example using data augmentation.

Comment: i used image augmentation but its not improving results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Large number of parameters are prone to overfitting. This is the case, iff your training accuracy is close to 100 percent, while your validation accuracy is only mid 50 percent. If this is the case you might want to take a look at transfer learning (https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-using-keras-d804b2e04ef8). This is one of the techniques used to fit smaller datasets.

Comment: my training accuracy is around 0.777 while validation accuracy 0.333 and 0.5632

Comment: seems quite low. You should be able to learn this dataset with your model and easily get 100 percent training acc. This appears to be a bug in the code. Check the input data to your network and the code of the network.

Comment: transfer learning throwing error of input must have 3 channels

Comment: if i post my whole code can you check why it is showing low accuracy